# Using "BETEEN" operator on a LONG-EMBEDDED-LIST property declared in OrientDB 2.2.17

Tags: orientdb, orientdb-2.1

I am using OrientDB 2.2.17 (enterprise edition) and I have a problem searching on the data:

1. I have a vertex called: EN70 with a property: EP70_4 from type 'embedded list = LONG'.
2. I added a record to this vertex with the value of [2,3,4] in this 'EP70_4' property.
3. The index on this property: Not_Unique (sbtree). [must support range queries]
4. SELECT * FROM EN70 WHERE (EP70_4 >= 1) is working and returns my record.
5. SELECT * FROM EN70 WHERE (EP70_4 <= 3) is working and returns my record.
6. The operator "Between" is not woking and throw exception:
   SELECT * FROM EN70 WHERE (EP70_4 BETWEEN 1 AND 3 )
7. I tried to simulate a "between" operator: 
   SELECT * FROM EN70 WHERE ((EP70_4 >= 1) AND (EP70_4 <= 3)) IS NOT WORKING
   but it is not working.

both sections 6 and 7 throws an exception:

Error on using index EN70.EP70_4 in query 'SELECT * FROM EN70 WHERE (EP70_4 BETWEEN 1 AND 3 )'. Probably you need to rebuild indexes. Now executing query using cluster scan
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to java.lang.Long
        at com.orientechnologies.common.serialization.types.OLongSerializer.preprocess(OLongSerializer.java:36)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.index.sbtree.local.OSBTree.iterateEntriesBetweenAscOrder(OSBTree.java:1474)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.index.sbtree.local.OSBTree.iterateEntriesBetween(OSBTree.java:771)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.index.engine.OSBTreeIndexEngine.iterateEntriesBetween(OSBTreeIndexEngine.java:185)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.OAbstractPaginatedStorage.doIterateIndexEntriesBetween(OAbstractPaginatedStorage.java:2065)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.OAbstractPaginatedStorage.iterateIndexEntriesBetween(OAbstractPaginatedStorage.java:2053)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.index.OIndexMultiValues.iterateEntriesBetween(OIndexMultiValues.java:275)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.index.OIndexAbstractDelegate.iterateEntriesBetween(OIndexAbstractDelegate.java:104)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.index.OIndexTxAwareMultiValue.iterateEntriesBetween(OIndexTxAwareMultiValue.java:339)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.sql.operator.OQueryOperatorBetween.executeIndexQuery(OQueryOperatorBetween.java:131)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.sql.OCommandExecutorSQLSelect.searchForIndexes(OCommandExecutorSQLSelect.java:2184)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.sql.OCommandExecutorSQLSelect.searchInClasses(OCommandExecutorSQLSelect.java:1001)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.sql.OCommandExecutorSQLResultsetAbstract.assignTarget(OCommandExecutorSQLResultsetAbstract.java:209)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.sql.OCommandExecutorSQLSelect.assignTarget(OCommandExecutorSQLSelect.java:530)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.sql.OCommandExecutorSQLSelect.executeSearch(OCommandExecutorSQLSelect.java:512)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.sql.OCommandExecutorSQLSelect.execute(OCommandExecutorSQLSelect.java:488)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.sql.OCommandExecutorSQLDelegate.execute(OCommandExecutorSQLDelegate.java:74)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.OAbstractPaginatedStorage.executeCommand(OAbstractPaginatedStorage.java:2624)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.OAbstractPaginatedStorage.command(OAbstractPaginatedStorage.java:2570)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.command.OCommandRequestTextAbstract.execute(OCommandRequestTextAbstract.java:69)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.network.protocol.http.command.post.OServerCommandPostCommand.execute(OServerCommandPostCommand.java:106)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.graph.server.command.OServerCommandPostCommandGraph.execute(OServerCommandPostCommandGraph.java:37)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.network.protocol.http.ONetworkProtocolHttpAbstract.service(ONetworkProtocolHttpAbstract.java:169)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.network.protocol.http.ONetworkProtocolHttpAbstract.execute(ONetworkProtocolHttpAbstract.java:622)
        at com.orientechnologies.common.thread.OSoftThread.run(OSoftThread.java:77)

What can it be??? Please help me...

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  
Please take the tour stackoverflow.com/tour,  
learn asking good questions stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask,  
make a MCVE stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  
An MCVE in this case would be a minimised database (structure and content) and simplified query. Making it might help you find the answer. Or help others finding it.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say it's a bug, I strongly suggest you to report it here: https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/issues

Comment: Thank you very much, I just pushed a fix on branch 2.2.x, the fix will be released with 2.2.20